# Best c++ method to store small amounts of data for later use

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I need to store a small amount of data (between 1 and 5 characters) and I would like to know the best way to go about doing it.

I need to be able to read it when the application first starts and if the file doesn't exist, create it and save data to it (or if it does exist, read the data and put it in a variable).

Any guidance and code examples given on any of these problems will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As described `new` would solve your problem, as you did not describe how long the data needs to persist.

Comment: missing what have you tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write and read your data from a file. If you want to find out how to read and write files in C++ you can try the following tutorial:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 1):

For the file management you could use [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/). (Aka, ifstream, ofstream, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a file and write the data. That's pretty much the only way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. write to files using fstream
2. if the data could be sorted into key/value tuples you could also use the windows registery

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows you can use the Windows Registry (look it up in the Visual Studio docs). I don't necessarily recommend that, a file may be more convenient, but it is a standard Windows technique.